# How to update IOptions after having built the configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-core

**Context:**
In Integration Testings, we need to test different cases with different options. I dont want to create a TestServerFixture different for each test.

**Request:**
I m looking for a possibility to update globally the IOptions.

TestServerFixture:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Data {get; set;} = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"identity:claimsidentity:roleclaimtype", roleClaimType},
            {"identity:claimsidentity:usernameclaimtype", usernameClaimType},
            {"identity:claimsidentity:useridclaimtype", useridClaimType},
            {"identity:claimsidentity:securitystampclaimtype", securityStampClaimType},
            {"identity:user:requireUniqueEmail", "true"},
            {"identity:password:RequiredLength", "10"},
            {"identity:password:RequireNonAlphanumeric", "false"},
            {"identity:password:RequireUpperCase", "false"},
            {"identity:password:RequireDigit", "false"},
            {"identity:password:RequireLowerCase", "false"},
            {"identity:lockout:AllowedForNewUsers", "FALSe"},
            {"identity:lockout:MaxFailedAccessAttempts", "1000"}
        };

[..]

var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, builder) =>
    {
        builder
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(Data);
    })
    [..]
```

Tests:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Do_Something()
    {
        // When I do a call to the server, identity:user:requireUniqueEmail will be true


        TestServerFixture.Data = //New Data with identity:user:requireUniqueEmail  = false;

        // When I do a call to the server, identity:user:requireUniqueEmail will be false
    }
```

So each time I set a new value to the property Data, automatically it will update the current configuration.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried saving your changes to the `appsettings.json` file instead of trying to do it in memory? The Builder should notice the changes and reload the settings for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I would like to avoid to update the appsettings.json.